# How can I set up dynamic meta tag for seperate Express and React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, meta-tags

I have a hobby project that uses **NodeJS - Express** and deploys it to [***OnRender***](https://render.com/) site - similar to ***Heroku***, on the other hand, I have a **React** app that deploys to [***Vercel***](https://vercel.com/).

I have searched and everyone usually implements **Express** alongside **React** and does **SSR** - ***Server Side Rendering*** with it. But now my project is separate, is it possible to somehow set up for my **Express** to replace meta tags of ***index.html*** file from frontend when sharing it to other social media?

I saw a guide and they do a tree folder like this to achieve it:

```
.
└── Project/
    ├── build
    ├── public/
    │   └── index.html
    ├── src
    └── server.js
```

From there, they use Node to render the HTML
Something like this:

```
const express = require("express")
const path = require("path")
const fs = require("fs")
const app = express()

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
const indexPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "build", "index.html")

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "build")))
// Serve the index.html page
app.get("/*", (req, res, next) => {
    fs.readFile(indexPath, "utf8", (err, htmlData) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Error during file reading", err)
            return res.status(404).end()
        }

        const { post } = req.query

        // inject meta tags
        htmlData = htmlData
            .replace("<title>React App</title>", `<title>${post.title}</title>`)
            .replace("__META_OG_TITLE__", post.title)
            .replace("__META_OG_DESCRIPTION__", post.description)
            .replace("__META_DESCRIPTION__", post.description)
            .replace("__META_OG_IMAGE__", post.thumbnail)
        return res.send(htmlData)
    })
})
// listening...
app.listen(PORT, (error) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.log("Error when startup", error)
    }
    console.log("listening on " + PORT + "...")
})
```

But the problem is, this is only doable if bundled in one. I find no method I can achieve to write the ***index.html*** from my separate backend and replace it in the frontend.

My project looks like this.

**React** on Vercel:

```
.
└── Frontend React Project/
    ├── public/
    │   └── index.html
    └── src
```

**Express** on onRender:

```
.
└── Backend Express Project/
    └── src/
        ├── model.js
        ├── routes.js
        ├── controller.js
        └── index.js
```

Is there really a way to achieve the dynamic meta tags when sharing to the social site with separate frontend and backend? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have to get your meta data in your express response. You can check the example.

```
import {useEffect} from 'react'
import Head from 'next/head'


function IndexPage() {
const [metaData,setMetaData] = React.useState({})

useEffect(()=>{
const getPageData = ()=>{
// api call and get data
setMetaData(fetchedData);
}

getPageData()
},[])

  return (
    <div>
      {
    metaData && <Head>
        <title>{metaData.title}</title>
      </Head>

}
      <p>Hello world!</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default IndexPage
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head

Comment: Does this require me to implement NEXT.js in my project? I'm just wondering because I'm still using ReactJS, but if it does, I'll gladly give it a try. And from then on, do I just need to pour my data from Express to this IndexPage only? Or it can be multiple pages? Thanks.

Comment: You can use your every page for specific head tags. Especially have to use your dynamic pages.